# Android parcelable data between activities. Getting NullPointerException when I try to read data

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, parcelable

I need to pass an custom object array from an activity to other one. When i try to read data in the second activity, I get a "NullPointerException" error, and the app brake.

This is my parcelable object:

```
package com.tapsistemas.avcanquake;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class TipoEvento implements Parcelable {

private String evento;
private String latitud;
private String longitud;
private String profundidad;
private String localizacion;
private String magnitud;

public TipoEvento() {
}

public void setEvento(String ev){
    this.evento = ev;
}

public String getEvento(){
    return evento;
}

public void setLatitud(String lat){
    this.latitud = lat;
}

public String getLatitud(){
    return latitud;
}

public void setLongitud(String lon){
    this.longitud = lon;
}

public String getLongitud(){
    return longitud;
}

public void setProfundidad(String prof){
    this.profundidad = prof;
}

public String getProfundidad(){
    return profundidad;
}

public void setLocalizacion(String loc){
    this.localizacion = loc;
}

public String getLocalizacion(){
    return localizacion;
}

public void setMagnitud(String mag){
    this.magnitud = mag;
}

public String getMagnitud(){
    return magnitud;
}

public TipoEvento(Parcel parcel){
    readToParcel(parcel);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = 
        new Parcelable.Creator() {

    public TipoEvento createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new TipoEvento(source);
    }

    public TipoEvento[] newArray(int size) {
        return new TipoEvento[size];
    }

};

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeString(evento);
    parcel.writeString(latitud);
    parcel.writeString(longitud);
    parcel.writeString(profundidad);
    parcel.writeString(localizacion);
    parcel.writeString(magnitud);
}

public void readToParcel(Parcel parcel){
    evento = parcel.readString();
    latitud = parcel.readString();
    longitud = parcel.readString();
    profundidad = parcel.readString();
    localizacion = parcel.readString();
    magnitud = parcel.readString();
}

}
```

Here, I fill my object Array with data (it's into an OnPostExecute):

```
                    TipoEvento sismo = new TipoEvento();

                sismo.setEvento(obj.getString("E"));
                sismo.setLocalizacion(obj.getString("Loc"));
                sismo.setLatitud(obj.getString("Lat"));
                sismo.setLongitud(obj.getString("Lon"));
                sismo.setProfundidad(obj.getString("Prof"));
                Eventos.add(sismo);
```

Here, I send array data and launch the second activity:

```
    botonMapa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent nuevoIntent = new Intent(context, mapa.class);
            nuevoIntent.putExtra("datos", Eventos);
            startActivity(nuevoIntent);

        }
    });
```

Here, I try to get the data in the second activity:

```
Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();
Eventos = datos.getParcelable("datos");
```

And here is the problem. When I try to use this data, I get NullPointerException. If I comment this lines, my app runs OK.

```
int contador = Eventos.size();

for (i=1; i<contador; i++){
    String lat = Eventos.get(i).getLatitud();
    String lon = Eventos.get(i).getLongitud();
    String loc = Eventos.get(i).getLocalizacion();
    String pro = Eventos.get(i).getProfundidad();
}
```

Thank you for your interest, and sorry by my poor English.

EDIT:

This is the LogCat of the crash:

```
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tapsistemas.avcanquake/com.tapsistemas.avcanquake.mapa}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.tapsistemas.avcanquake.mapa.onCreate(mapa.java:39)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-25 09:54:04.619: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your logcat from the crash.

Comment: What is at line 39 of `mapa`? Something there is `null`. You need to see what it is and trace back from there to see why it is `null`.

Comment: This one: String lat = Eventos.get(i).getLatitud(); (Is the first line I try to read incoming data)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
for (i=1; i<contador; i++){
   String lat = Eventos.get(i).getLatitud();
   String lon = Eventos.get(i).getLongitud();
   String loc = Eventos.get(i).getLocalizacion();
   String pro = Eventos.get(i).getProfundidad();
}
```

with

```
for (i=0; i<contador; i++){
   String lat = Eventos.get(i).getLatitud();
   String lon = Eventos.get(i).getLongitud();
   String loc = Eventos.get(i).getLocalizacion();
   String pro = Eventos.get(i).getProfundidad();
}
```

I think your Eventos list is having only one element and you are trying to access second element (index with 1) which is not there in list. (size 1 -> index 0) (size 2 -> index 0,1)

Comment: Yes, starting value is 0, I only set it to 1 looking for the error. And testing and testing I forgot set it to 0 again. Thankyou and Happy Christmas!